# Change rostest max time allotted

Tags: ros, rostest, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

I am doing a rostest and want known if is it possible to change the "max time allotted" parameter

Thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10902/change-rostest-max-time-allotted/) by [gainerems](https://answers.ros.org/users/692/gainerems/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a time-limit parameter in the [XML syntax](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/test)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gainerems](https://answers.ros.org/users/692/gainerems/) on 2011-08-17**:
nice, thank you

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2017-06-12**:
@tfoote Sorry for hijacking the question, but it is related. This timer uses the wall time right? I couldn't find any evidence other than triggeering earlier than expected when Gazebo runs at 0.3 time factor.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-12**:
Yes it's what we call wall time. It's just timeouts from gtest/python unit testing frameworks. Otherwise if the simulation hung the test would never time out.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2017-06-28**:
Makes sense. Thanks a lot!